# C++ using declaration vs type aliases in headers

Tags: c++, c++11

In a C++11 project I would like to introduce a few identifiers from the standard library namespace (`std`) into the project's namespace (`proj`) to enhace readability.  For example I would prefer to be able to use `string` everywhere instead of `std::string`.

Note that this project is an application, not a library whose code will be subsequently included by other projects.

This could be achieved by adding code to a common header included everywhere in the project.  Two methods of actually introducing the identifier are shown below:

```
#ifndef PROJ_H
#define PROJ_H

#include "stuff.h"
#include <string>

namespace proj
{
  // method 1 - using declaration
  using std::string;

  // method 2 - type alias
  using string = std::string;
}

#endif
```

I have a feeling that method 2 is superior to method 1.  The reason being that if `stuff.h` introduces a `string` identifier to the anonymous namespace then use of `string` from inside the `proj` namespace will be ambiguous.

My questions:

1. Is method 2 really superior as I suggest or are they strictly equivalent?
2. If method 2 is better, how can I achieve the same level of safety for a non-type identifier (such as a function like `std::make_unique`).

Comment: _"if `stuff.h` introduces a `string` identifier to the anonymous namespace then use of `string` from inside the `proj` namespace will be ambiguous."_ No it won't. Besides, anonymous namespaces in headers are rare anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Hmm, interesting.  I assumed that `using std::string` would have the same ambiguity problem as `using namespace std`.  It seems that identifiers included individually are much stronger than members included as part of a namespace.  Do you know why this is?  The inconsistency seems a bit painful.

Comment: Because they're not the same. Why should two different features with different uses be consistent? That would be redundant.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't agree with that reasoning.  From the programmer's point of view the two uses are "I want to make this name visible" and "I want to make all names from this namespace visible".  Assigning different semantics to the two 'make visible' actions is misleading.

Comment: That programmer's point of view is not what what the language says, I can't help it if a mistaken understanding doesn't match reality :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are equal and you can proove that by using a `static_assert` in your namespace.

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, string>::value, "types are not the same"); // succeeds and does NOT complain
```

> string identifier to the anonymous namespace then use of string from inside the proj namespace will be ambiguous.

In that case you write only `::string` to specify which string you want to use.

```
::string s1;

string s2;
```

What you can't do is to introduce a new type or typedef-name in namespace `proj`. I prefer to use the `using declaration` to indicate it's still the same type. Although the alias-declaration does NOT introduce a new type it feels like a new one for semantics - but that's just a personal thing.